# How to add a flash game to my facebook APP

Tags: facebook, flash

I tried adding a flash game to my APP.

I looked on the (terrible) facebook developer website. All I found was this page:
[http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Ffbml%2Fswf%2F&ei=e-CXT4SAMMfpOamGqb8G&usg=AFQjCNGCKaCIDbWs0PrItofyEIlR4MSasg](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/swf/&ei=e-CXT4SAMMfpOamGqb8G&usg=AFQjCNGCKaCIDbWs0PrItofyEIlR4MSasg)

But it says this will be legacy code and I should use a new method... I have no clue what that method is or where I can find it.

I tried these lines:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://mywebsite.com/game.swf" />
```

and

```
<fb:swf swfsrc='http://mywebsite.com/game.swf' imgsrc='http://www.myurl.com/myflash.jpg' width='400′ height='300′ />
```

both failed... I'm desperate here, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an iframe application. That means create a page for your flash game to run on its own and then just point the iframe app to that url

Answer (score 0):

Do exacly as on http://ugamesfree.com
Create a canvas app on facebook.
But remember, you need to have a SSL certificate to use iframes and redirects.